# UIView in xib displays as portrait when opened in landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I just added a separate view controller and xib in a project that uses storyboards throughout. I display it from inside another view controller with the usual code:

```
OtherVC *othervc = [[OtherVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView: othervc.view];
```

In portrait orientation, he xib displays and auto rotates properly right out of the box.

But when I display it when the iPad is already in landscape, the size of the view is portrait and positioned off to the left.

What's going on? There doesn't seem to be a way to add constraints to the view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to present a separate `viewController`.

The problem is that you are adding a view on the actual view..but **this view have a certain frame that will remain the same when you add it on the view**..**in both case** (`landscape` and `protrait`). So, to understand, **you should check the orientation and then set the frame of the view properly**. But as i said, **the way that you are using is wrong.**

In your case **you should** use `segue` from **storyboard**.

Or, at max, by code but with something like:

```
OtherVC *othervc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
[self presentViewController:othervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where `Identifier` is set in your `viewController` in the storyboard by the inspector panel at the right.

Or, if you instead wanted to say "**NIB**" you should to do:

```
OtherVC *othervc = [[OtherVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; //Or your correct bundle but i guess will be this.
[self presentViewController:othervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So after this, if you are sure to have set both orientation on your project, your view will be in landscape.

Now you will use `AutoLayout` or normal mask rules without AutoLayout to manage the elements on the view.

Comment: I think you should update the answer to work with a xib file to coincide with the OP's current situation. You can offer multiple "better" suggestions after dealing with the actual facts (which indicate that the OP is using a xib file and storyboards).

Comment: if he are using storyboard he should use SEGUE. But i think that he are using a separate NIB and not XIB. But in any case, i suggest the correct way to operate but also propose a solution for him. But again, i encourage to change way and implement all in a correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I could do it the ways you suggest, but the view controller I'm adding has a background view that's semi-transparent and if I use a segue or a presentViewController, they both remove the original background view which is not what I want. My original way, shows the background through the transparent view and works fine except for the orientation issue.

Comment: So you can follow my first suggest. Before add the new view you should check the orientation if is landscape or portrait and set the frame of the new view properly.

Comment: Based on my intended usage, I can see that this is not the way to go. I'm just going to use a custom alert view instead. Thank again.